# How to overcome error when adding a sprite

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite

I'm trying to make this game, but when i'm adding a sprite it says this " Cannot invoke initializer for type 'SKSpriteNode?' with no arguments "
[image]

Comment: try `var myNinja: SKSpriteNode?` to declare the variable as an optional *type*

Comment: Then it just says, that i need to change it to " = "

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are 2 things with your code.

1 - This specific error occurs because there are no initializers for `SKSpriteNode` that takes no argument as you tried to use. You can take a look at [`SKSpriteNode` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skspritenode) to see which initializer best fit your code.

2 - Maybe what you need is declare your variable like this `var myNinja: SKSpriteNode? = SKSpriteNode()`

Comment: The "var" works now, but now it's the function that says error " Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage' to expected argument type 'String"  https://imgur.com/a/3Gg4kaO

Comment: This is happening because this specific initializer should receive the image name as `String`, not as a `UIImage` as you're doing in the image you shared.